# Organize Maven Dependency in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I know how to add maven dependencies in eclipse. But I am looking for organizing them.

After issuing

```
eclipse:eclipse
```

and importing the project in the eclipse, all the dependency library appears.

Now from what i have experience all the dependent jar were all under the "Maven Dependencies". But i see all the jar are loose - just under the project name.

Basically what i am interested is from

[image]

to this :

[image]

Comment: I can't see the images as they are blocked but based on what you describe, try using the Java EE perspective instead of the Java perspective.

Comment: Its in  the Java EE perspective

Comment: Try importing the project using the eclipse m2e plugin instead of calling `eclipse:eclipse` to generate the project file.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and importing as existing project, got to

`File-> Import-> Maven-> Existing Maven Projects`

and select your project from there. If you do it that way, your maven dependencies should come up under `Maven Dependencies` section.

Comment: Its not even showing as maven java project. Just maven project after importing.

Comment: @Zeta Do you mean when following above instructions?. Can you try  right click-> Maven -> update project?

Comment: Can you try the following. Remove the project from Eclipse. Remove the eclipse specific files manually (.classpath, .settings, .project), then import again into Eclipse using above method.

Comment: Interesting - Just found when importing in Juno its fine... But in Mars it doesn`t..